# How to redirect page on Jquery validation success

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery for validation
set some rules.

If validation success I want to redirect to another page.
How can I do it?

```
// validate contact form on keyup and submit
$("#contactForm").validate({
    //set the rules for the field names
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: 4
        },

    },
    //set messages to appear inline
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your name",
        password: "Please enter your email"
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your redirect logic in `submitHandler` callback. I think you want to set the `window.url` to a diff url. right?

Comment: yes... after entering registration details ..show success another page
thnks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `submitHandler` option to `validate` like so:

```
$("#contactForm").validate({
   ...
   submitHandler: function(form) {    
      window.location = "http://your.url.here";
   }   
});
```

So when you validate the form, `submitHandler` is called if the form validated successfully, and there you redirect the user.

Comment: `.validate()` calls `submitHandler`, calling it inside would cause an infinite loop, there's no need to call it in there.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Fixing it now. The documentation suggested that `validate()` be called before `valid()`. I didn't realize that calling `validate()` by itself also calls `submitHandler`.

Comment: There's no need to check `.valid()` either, if you're running you're valid, otherwise you're in the `invalidHandler`:)

Comment: @Nick haha - that's a good point. Looks like I've completely borked this up - fixing again.

Answer (score 0):

Call `window.location.replace='http://www.newpage.com';`. Not jQuery specific.